# how can i access this matlab matrix element?

Tags: matlab, fft

this is a Fourier descriptor for a set of points

```
a =

  -3.4173 - 7.1634i
   7.4589 + 0.1321i
   3.1190 - 2.1870i
  -7.1979 + 0.2863i
   5.9594 + 0.8209i
  -5.4295 -15.7931i
  -1.0957 + 3.7485i
   0.2657 - 4.1459i
   7.4644 - 0.9546i
```

i need to sum each pair , but when i use a(1) or a(1,1) it produces   -3.4173 - 7.1634i
when i use abs(a(1)) or abs(a(1,1)) it also produces     7.9367 which does not make sense for me !

what i need is how to access each element of any pair individually so i get -3.4173 alone and - 7.1634i alone as well so i can do normalization on it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of complex numbers, and what you want to do is access the real and imaginary parts of each number.

```
r = real(a);
i = imag(a);
```

will result in `r` and `i` containing real and imaginary parts of your descriptor respectively.

To understand the reason you get an answer that "doesn't make any sense" from `abs(a(1))`, follow [this link](http://www.clarku.edu/~djoyce/complex/abs.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your data type looks confusing because `a(1,1)` shouldn't give you back the imaginary part of a number... your array should just be 1-dimensional if the values are just complex numbers.  But try using the `real()` and `imag()` functions on the elements of your array, which will return the real and imaginary parts respectively. You might want to consider using a different data structure though, because Matlab can handle regular complex values just fine, and in that case simply using `abs()` should give the modulus of the number.